# Python BeautifulSoup looping through live prices

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get prices for a specific item in different locations across the US. The site has a text box where you can enter a state and it updates the price but the URL remains the same. In the Developer Tools the location changes depending on your input which updates the price. I'm trying to scrape the prices with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/equipment/detail/1255/0350140/7500lb-mini-excavator/').text


soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    # Finding the equipment name and printing it

name_article = soup.find('div', id = 'equipment-catalog-page-container')

    # This pricing is based off of typing "NC" into the search box

equipment_name = name_article.h1.text
print(equipment_name)


for price_article in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'info--price'):
    equipment_price = price_article.text
    print(equipment_price)
```

and the output is:

```
7,500lb Mini Excavator

Online Rate: 

1 Day: {{RateDaily | toCurrency}} {{Currency}}
1 Week: {{RateWeekly | toCurrency}} {{Currency}}
4 Weeks: {{RateMonthly | toCurrency}} {{Currency}}

The displayed rates do not include the taxes or optional charges that may be selected later in the checkout process.
```

For reference, the HTML code from the developer tools for the pricing aspect is this:

```
   <div class="info--price" v-if="showRates">
<span class="ratesSubtitle">
 Online Rate:
</span>
<br/>
<ul class="menu">
 <li style="margin-right: 10px;">
  1 Day:
  <strong>
   {{RateDaily | toCurrency}}
  </strong>
  {{Currency}}
 </li>
 <li style="margin-right: 10px;">
  1 Week:
  <strong>
   {{RateWeekly | toCurrency}}
  </strong>
  {{Currency}}
 </li>
 <li style="margin-right: 10px;">
  4 Weeks:
  <strong>
   {{RateMonthly | toCurrency}}
  </strong>
  {{Currency}}
 </li>
</ul>
<small>
 The displayed rates do not include the taxes or optional charges that may be selected later in the checkout process.
</small>
```

On the developer tools screen, where it says {{RateMonthly | toCurrency }} there is a price (example: $1,125) and where it says {{Currency}} it says " USD". I can't figure out how to get these to display the actual price on the developer tools.

I'm not sure if it is important, but here is the developer tools for the location:

```
<div id="jobsite-instance">
 <jobsite-display inline-template="" v-cloak="">
  <div v-if="showJobsite">
   <div class="jobsite_location" v-show="!showInput">
    <p>
     Jobsite Location
    </p>
    <p style="cursor: pointer;" v- 
 on:click.prevent="showInput=true">
     <span class="location raised">
      {{currentLocation}}
     </span>
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" 
style="margin-left: 4px;">
     </i>
    </p>
   </div>
   <shopping-location-selector :current- 
location="currentLocation" v-show="showInput">
   </shopping-location-selector>
  </div>
 </jobsite-display>
</div>
```

Where it says {{currentLocation}}, it says ', NC' on my screen. I'm not sure how to work around these variables, am I doing something incorrectly? My next steps will be to create a loop to change the search location so I can use it to get the prices across different states.